# Do LTS releases get the features from normal releases through the update process?

Tags: updates, lts, stable-release-updates

Does every major LTS update inherit the features of the preceding normal Ubuntu version? I mean, did 12.04.2 inherit features from 12.10, and will 12.04.3 get the features from 13.04? Or will those features be implemented in the future 14.04 LTS?

I like the features of 13.04 and want to know whether future 12.04.3 will get the nice features of 13.04, or whether I will need to upgrade to 13.04 to enjoy its features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to upgrade to 13.04 to enjoy its features.

With few exceptions, new features are not added to any Ubuntu release post-release. The exceptions are for hardware enablement (making 12.04 work on hardware released after the release of 12.04) and software like Firefox which are generally driven by upstreams and fulfil certain requirements.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates/MicroReleaseExceptions for details.

Comment: It's likely that new Unity versions will be also backported to 12.04. Or at least there has been some talking about it on the planet.